# How to implement this with a simple for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

The problem is as follows:
(This is my first Matlab code)
So, I have a velocity fixes, e.g.

```
Mach=0.2
```

For that I have coefficients that I use further in calculations, e.g.

```
CL0=0.3956+0.0101*Mach+0.0657*Mach^2+0.1438*Mach^3;
CLa=5.7814+0.1402*Mach+0.959*Mach^2+2.008*Mach^3; etc.
```

these I use later when calculating roots of the characteristic polynomial of the matrix A.
Then I take the roots to calculate the following:

```
delta_SP=real(s(1));
omega_SP=imag(s(1));
omegan_SP=sqrt(delta_SP^2+omega_SP^2);
zeta_SP=-delta_SP/sqrt(delta_SP^2+omega_SP^2);
```

The problem is when I want to do this for several `Mach` numbers, ranging

```
Mach=0.2:0.1:0.8
```

can you please help me with a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below

```
i = 1;
CL0 = 0;
CLa = 0;
for Mach = 0.2:0.1:0.8
    CL0(i) = 0.3956+0.0101*Mach+0.0657*Mach^2+0.1438*Mach^3;
    CLa(i) = 5.7814+0.1402*Mach+0.959*Mach^2+2.008*Mach^3;
    % and do all other calculations right over here according to your
    % problem
    i = i + 1;
end
```

Hope this helps . . .

Comment: @ivona Also keep in mind that while performing calculations in the `for` loop, you should use `CL0(i)` and `CLa(i)`.

Comment: thank you very much for your prompt answer. I'm trying and failing again.. Because these coefficients define other coefficients that define other coeff...that define the final result.. Should i put everywhere coeff(i)? They ARE connected with Mach number, directly or indirectly...

Comment: so there is a lot of changing to do..is there a possibility to put a loop later in a code somehow?

Comment: @ivona i think you can do it using nested `for` loops appropriately. Without fully understanding your problem, I am unable to give an exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

So in your question you don't relate `mach`, `CL0` and `CLa` to `s` and `delta` etc... but to generate all you CLa dna CL0 values you actually don't even need a loop:

```
Mach=0.2:0.1:0.8;
CL0=0.3956+0.0101*Mach+0.0657*Mach.^2+0.1438*Mach.^3;
CLa=5.7814+0.1402*Mach+0.959*Mach.^2+2.008*Mach.^3;
```

Notice I used `.^` instead of just `^`, the dot means perform the power operator for each element of the matrix rather than on the matrix as a whole.

I can't comment on those other lines of your code because I don't see how they connect?

Comment: Connection between parameteres:

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't use the word "Don't Know How" in the title, it strays people away from your post.

Comment: won't do in the future.. BR